# he slug “sub category” is already in use by another term

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How you deal it with woocommerce website. I am creating following categories in WooCommerce:

- Buy > Display > Mobile > Iphone 14
- Buy > Screen Protector > Mobile > Iphone 14

Is it possible to have the same sub-category slug under each parent category?

Example cateogy should look like that -

- example.com/display/mobile/iphone-14
- example.com/screen-protector/mobile/iphone-14

When I try this, WordPress throws up the error message:

The slug “sub category” is already in use by another term.

It's important to have duplicate sub-categories.

How Can i Solve this issue.